# How to confirm that the test case is synchronized properly with HP ALM?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

How to confirm that the test case is synchronized properly with HP ALM ?

Answer (score 0):

Sync/Upload the test case to ALM using the eclipse configuration **ALM Sync**

**createTestCase [flow_id] [flow_xml_path]**

Avoid spaces in Flow ID and Flow XML Path.

After Sync has happened, Follow the below steps:

1. User needs to make sure that "Hasta La vista" is displayed in the console then test cases are successfully synchronized.
2. Refresh your ALM and see whether you can view the test case under the desired folder.
3. Verify alm_test_id value with the testcase uploaded